# llegalStateException: couldn't move cursor to position

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-spinner, simplecursoradapter

There is a spinner which is populated with contacts from device.

```
Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER +" = "+ HAS_PHONE_NUMBER_STATE, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME +" ASC");

SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, contactsCursor, new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

contactsSpinner.setAdapter(sca);
```

When I attempt so set sellection

```
String contactId = getContactSelectedId();      
if(null != contactId) {
    contactsSpinner.setSelection(Integer.valueOf(contactId));
}
```

Rises an exception:

```
llegalStateException: couldn't move cursor to position x
```

**Stacktrace**:

```
07-31 01:07:08.854: E/AndroidRuntime(22745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 01:07:08.854: E/AndroidRuntime(22745): java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't move cursor to position 1136
07-31 01:07:08.854: E/AndroidRuntime(22745):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:248)
07-31 01:07:08.854: E/AndroidRuntime(22745):    at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:544)
07-31 01:07:08.854: E/AndroidRuntime(22745):    at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:495)
07-31 01:07:08.854: E/AndroidRuntime(22745):    at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:459)
07-31 01:07:08.854: E/AndroidRuntime(22745):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
07-31 01:07:08.854: E/AndroidRuntime(22745):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
07-31 01:07:08.854: E/AndroidRuntime(22745):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
07-31 01:07:08.854: E/AndroidRuntime(22745):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: This code works for me. Check what returns `getContactSelectedId`. It should returns not Id but index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setSelection(int position)` function take a position as a parameter,
 but you give the function the ID of the selected item.

You need create a function `getContactSelectedPosition()` or something like that.
This function would (potentially) loop through the data for the adapter and then return the position of the matching contact